# ORACLE Order By number first in string field

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I can not figure how to set this `order by` in this query.
I want to order by first by numbers and then by char. Maybe changing each character to HEX would work? I dont know. I will put the result when I order by

```
COLA   COLB
----   ----
00     1
000A   2
000B   2
000C   2
000D   2
000F   2
000G   2
000H   2
000I   2
0000   2
0001   2
0002   2
0003   2
00030A 3
00030B 3
000300 3
```

And what I want to get as result is this:

```
COLA   COLB
----   ----
00     1
0000   2
0001   2
0002   2
0003   2
000A   2
000B   2
000C   2
000D   2
000F   2
000G   2
000H   2
000I   2
000300 3
00030A 3
00030B 3
```

Thats my query:

```
with table1
as (
  select '00' COLA, 1 COLB from dual union
  select '000A' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000B' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000C' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000D' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000E' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000F' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000G' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000H' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000I' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '0000' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '0001' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '0002' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '0003' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '00030A' COLA, 3 COLB from dual union
  select '00030B' COLA, 3 COLB from dual union
  select '000300' COLA, 3 COLB from dual 
)
select * from table1 order by COLB, COLA
```

I already tried to use LPAD but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run your example in my database I get the 'correct' sort order as per your list.  Check you NLS_SORT setting; mine is set to BINARY.

Try it out by changing it for the session;

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort='BINARY';
```

There are lots of possibilities for this parameter so if you want to experiment you can find the possibilities in the V$NLS_VALID_VALUES view.

I've also just spotted that you can do the following;

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY colb, NLSSORT(cola, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY')
```

Comment: Thanks. My NLS_SORT was set to **WEST_EUROPEAN**. I used the ORDER BY setting the NLSSORT and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to extract the number:

```
order by colb,
         cast(regexp_substr(cola, '[0-9]', 1, 1) as number),
         cola
```

Comment: When I use the cast function in the string '000A', the result is '0', so the order by still get the same result.

Comment: I used ```cast(regexp_substr(cola, '[0-9]', 1, 1) as number), 
cast(regexp_substr(cola, '[0-9]', 2, 1) as number), 
cast(regexp_substr(cola, '[0-9]', 3, 1) as number), 
cast(regexp_substr(cola, '[0-9]', 4, 1) as number), 
cast(regexp_substr(cola, '[0-9]', 5, 1) as number), 
cast(regexp_substr(cola, '[0-9]', 6, 1) as number), ``` and it worked. Thanks. 
The bad thing is that this field is 90 length

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
with table1
as (
 select '00' COLA, 1 COLB from dual union
select '000A' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '000B' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '000C' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '000D' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '000E' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '000F' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '000G' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '000H' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '000I' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '0000' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '0001' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '0002' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '0003' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
select '00030A' COLA, 3 COLB from dual union
select '00030B' COLA, 3 COLB from dual union
select '000300' COLA, 3 COLB from dual 
)
select * from table1 order by COLB, to_number(regexp_substr(COLA, '^[[:digit:]]*')), COLA
```

Comment: I doesn't work, as the function ```to_number(regexp...``` will change ```000A``` to ```0```.

Comment: I have tested this with value '00' , '0', '000', '000A' but its i working fine.

Comment: What is your oracle version?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Release 1: 12.1.0.2

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production. When I use your order by in the select i get al the stringsl values equal to 0 (zero), and get the number 0000 also equal to 0, so, the order by get the string first in its order by.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the TRANSLATE function :

```
  with table1 as (
  select '00' COLA, 1 COLB from dual union
  select '000A' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000B' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000C' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000D' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000E' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000F' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000G' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000H' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '000I' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '0000' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '0001' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '0002' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '0003' COLA, 2 COLB from dual union
  select '00030A' COLA, 3 COLB from dual union
  select '00030B' COLA, 3 COLB from dual union
  select '000300' COLA, 3 COLB from dual 
)
select * from table1 order by COLB, TRANSLATE(COLA,'0123456789','0123456789'),TRANSLATE(COLA,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
```